# China Mathematical Olympiad 2016 P5

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral. Show that there exists a square $A'B'C'D'$ (Vertices maybe ordered clockwise or counter-clockwise) such that $A \not = A', B \not = B', C \not = C', D \not = D'$ and $AA',BB',CC',DD'$ are all concurrent.

my progress: If $AC \perp BD$, take $P \equiv AC \cap BD$, and it is trivial to construct a square $A'B'C'D'$ with center $P$ such that $AA', BB', CC', DD'$ are concurrent at $P.$ Thus, suppose that $AC \not\perp BD.$ We will construct a point $P \in BD$ distinct from $B, D$ such that $\angle APB = \angle CPB.$

Let the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AC}$ meet $BD$ at $Q$ and let $P$ be the second intersection of $BD$ with $\odot(ACQ).$ Note that $Q$ is a midpoint of arc $\widehat{AC}$ on $\odot(ACQ)$ because $QA = QC.$ Therefore, $BD$ bisects $\angle APC.$ If $P$ coincides with $B$, repeat above construction about vertex $D$ instead of vertex $B.$ If $P$ then coincides with $D$, we have $\angle ABD = \angle CBD$ and $\angle ADB = \angle ACB.$ Therefore, $ABCD$ is a kite, implying that $AC \perp BD$, impossible. Thus, we may assume assume that $P \not\equiv B.$

Comment: Looks like you're done: what's the question?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca In what way is OP done? IE How is the original question solved? OP has just shown their progress, and has defined some point $P$, but doesn't seem to know how to use $P$ to create $A'B'C'D'$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Maybe... but that looks quite obvious to me...